# Archiving emails as individual text files + attachments on newer OSs than XP (like Express Archiver)?

Tags: email, backup

I'm looking for Windows 7, MacOS and Ubuntu Linux equivalents of Express Archiver for Windows XP   that archived Outlook Express emails to individual files.

http://www.expressarchiver.com/

This program does the job so well: It archives the whole email plus headers, provides a multitude of options for naming the file based on email content, provides unique naming should 2 email files have the same name, attachment options put in a sub-folder etc.

It means that the archived files do not rely on a specific program to view them. Emails are plain text, attachments are files placed in a folder. Email as separate files are convenient to manage, move around, organise and search using standard tools.

I haven't found a tool for the newer OSs though, and XP and Outlook Express are becoming obsolete.

thoughts?

Comment: Related question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30431/imap-email-backup-to-eml-files-named-by-date-time-subject-sender-to-local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like they will do the job:

- Windows Mail to HTML Converter v.1.1
  (extracts out attachments too):
  http://www.emailadept.com/Windows-Mail-To-Html-Converter.htm
- Windows (Live) Mail to .eml:
  http://www.windowslivemailconverter.com/

Also for other mailbox clients that combine all emails into one file (e.g. Thunderbird), there is a program to export that into individual .eml files

- http://www.windowslivemailconverter.com/mbox.to.eml/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if I look at the Windows mail store folder - where the email is stored, then I can see that it is already in individual .eml files, the file name being a long-ish hexadecimal number. So there may not be a need for a 3rd party tool, just for me to write a Perl script (or other language) to rename these files as their subject heading and append an index in the event of same name collisions in the rename for files already with that name. For attachments it could be possible to uudecode the Mime base 64 ascii text that they are encoded in.

Also this tool:
http://bitdaddys.com/emldetach.html